# What'd be a formal way to say "морочить голову"?

Tags: idioms, formality

As in:

> приношу извинения что *морочил голову*

Context: made a booking but plans were cancelled.

Checked [ru.wiktionary.org](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83#.D0.A1.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.BC.D1.8B) and [frazbook.ru](http://frazbook.ru/2008/12/21/morochit-golovu/) but none of the suggested options sound natural.

Comment: `приношу извинения за неопределенность`?

Comment: приношу извинения за доставленное беспокойство

Comment: Извините, что ввел в заблуждение.

Comment: I don't think "сбивать с толку" is bad explanation. The expression itself is colloquical, however it can be used in that sense.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Прошу прощения за доставленные хлопоты, за беспокойство,за то, что отнял у Вас время. Any will do, I think.

Comment: `Простите за беспокойство` seems like the closest option, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

"Извините, что я вас напрасно обнадежил (обнадежила, if the speaker is female)" - это самое близкое по смыслу в данном случае. 
Но "извините, что отнял (отняла) у вас время" - самый стандартный вариант, вас сразу поймут.

Answer (score 2):

1) There should definitely be a comma behind "что" that you missed, such as "Извините, что побеспокоил", to mark another part of the sentence.
2) The list of possible synonims is very long, too long to be fully listed in here. However, here are some examples (partially already noted by V.V.):

- Извините, что (побеспокоил/отнял Ваше время/потревожил)
- Извините за (беспокойство/отнятое время/потраченное время)

...and many more! 
Good luck learning that complex language!